# Can a casio fx series do this operation?

Tags: telecommunication, radio

"Calculators stackexchange" doesn't exist, so I guessed this would be the right place to ask. Can a calculator solve $-0.2 \cdot e^{-0.06-4.2i}$?

Or any $e$ to a complex for that matter. I've been solving this with Wolfram Alpha or Matlab when in a project, but I'd like yo know if is there anyway to get it done in a calculator.

Comment: Can you please share the answer you expect from the expression?

Comment: How do you enter "i" ?

Comment: @SolarMike, you change the calculator mode into "complex mode" by pressing _mode_ then _2_.

Comment: @JemEripol does the OP know that? which is why I asked - I use an HP 28S...

Comment: Is there any reason other than tests in school where a calculator is prefered over a computer or a smartphone? I mean school requirements hook you to calculators but in reality thats a skill you should get rid of as soon as you leave shool.

Comment: @joojaa some of us when there is something to calculate will (still) automatically reach for a calculator and, personally, I find i can complete even complicated calculations / problems long before some people have had the computer boot, they log-in and then run the program etc... But your preference....

Comment: @SolarMike Your phone is always on, my computer is always on. The problem with using a calculator is that your ultimately setting yourself to fail, if you calculate on a computer you automatically document your work so that it can be checked and improved. All im saying is that this reflex may be unfounded and a bad habit of your educations need for a sandbox.

Comment: @joojaa if you think my education is down to a "bad habit" then perhaps you have a long way to go....

Comment: I was part way through my engineering degree when computers were changing from green or orange screens to colour and the first version of windows was coming online - but I had purchased an Atari ST with 4 meg of ram and it had a better GUI at the time... So, for some of us, we don't automatically go for a computer - we tend to use the grey matter more...

Comment: @SolarMike Thats fine im just saying even new engineers have often a skill lack in using computers. In either case gray matter does not document itself so the problem persists if you need to work with someones stuff.

Comment: @joojaa "The problem with using a calculator is that your ultimately setting yourself to fail" you dissed calculators not computers......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64936/discussion-between-joojaa-and-solar-mike).

Comment: FYI, calculators are mini computers too. :)

Comment: @JemEripol but that casio the OP mentioned can't store the works of Shakespeare in its native form (but my HP 28S will store text etc) unless you hack it.... but I agree the definition of these items can be cloudy...

Comment: @SolarMike, i know. That's why it is a mini computer. Casio can do a lot of things too.

Comment: Woha, quite a conversation over here. @JemEripol the result should be _0.0923421 -0.164164 i_ *jooja* it is indeed for a test, I do not use the calculator anytime else either. *SolarMike* I am familiar with using it with complex numbers, it simply prompts an error for this sort of operations.

Comment: @Alvai So, what is causing the error? if it handles other problems is this one outside its working range?

Comment: The calculator just won't take any of it, not even the simple e^(1-i). So I was just wondering if anyone found out a way to circumvent that.

Comment: So if it can't accept imaginary numbers as part of the exponent then unless you can re-do the expression to get rid of the exponent, the calculator won't do it...

Comment: There are actually dedicated casio calculator discussion forums (google). You should take this there.  FX-series goes back to 1978, you may want to be more specific as well.

Comment: You need specialized calculators to do this. This is beyond even your common graphing calculator. If your calculator can do it, you would have known it when you bought it. Some of the calculators that can do things like this have an interface *very* unlike what you are used to and it's a feat on its own getting used to them.